# Adding 0 Minutes with DATEADD

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking at some opportunities for performance tuning in my database and I've come across a select statement with this where clause:

```
WHERE GETDATE() > DATEADD(mi,0,[TimeStamp])
```

My question is, does it ever make sense to use DATEADD in this fashion?  I don't understand why the developer wouldn't simply use this instead:

```
WHERE GETDATE() > [TimeStamp]
```

Comment: I have not seen that one before; doesn't make sense to me either.

Comment: I agree. It seems pretty pointless. What is the datatype of TimeStamp?

Comment: Is Timestamp a date or datetime? Maybe someone is trying to "convert" to datetime for comparison? Seems unnecessary though.

Comment: Maybe some more context would help?

Comment: I would guess that this code evolved from a more complex original expression and when it ended up being `0`, the maintainer failed to observe that the `DATEADD` itself was no longer necessary. Check Source Control history.

Comment: Timestamp is a datetime

Comment: Maybe the original purpose is to specifically avoid using an index on `[TimeStamp]` -- as a way of getting around the optimizer.

Comment: This is my guess... someone might have had code like this to remove the time part of a date time: SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, '20170620 14:42'));  This is how you had to do this in early versions of SQL Server.  Over time this logic was amended, and what you are left with now is a pointless bit of SQL that doesn't do anything... Which is pretty much what has been said above, but with a little context?

Comment: Any way you slice it, a true timestamp would (should?) always be less than getdate().  So the developer is probably trying to do some kind of funky optimization.  Does it work?  If you simplify to your expression, is there a difference in performance?

Comment: @Greenspark actually a true timestamp has nothing at all to do with the time of day. It is a datatype in t-sql that is not the same as the ANSI standard timestamp. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql

Comment: @Sean Lange, op has specifically stated that [TimeStamp] is a datetime.  So, when I mention 'a true timestamp' I'm talking about the use of such a column, not the datatype used for version control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[1] `WHERE GETDATE() > [TimeStamp]` | `WHERE Expression > Column` | `WHERE Column < Expression` are SARG-able predicates and this means that DBMS (ex. SQL Server) could use `Index Seek` (or `Index Seek + Key|RID Lookup`) for execution plan in order to quickly find and return required rows.

[2] `WHERE GETDATE() > DATEADD(mi,0,[TimeStamp])` | `WHERE Expression > ScalarFunction(Column)` | `WHERE ScalarFunction(Column) < Expression` are not SARG-able predicates and this means that even if there is a proper index on `[Timestamp]` DBMS will not be able to use `Seek`. Instead a `Table|Index|Clustered Scan` operator will be used which have (*generally speaking **but not always***) lower performance than `Index Seek` (at least for OLTP systems).

So `DATEADD(mi,0,[TimeStamp])` forces a `Scan` data access operator to be used when execution plan is generated even if there is a proper index. Without `DATEADD` DBMS could use an `Seek` operator that could **not** be optimal choice for some/most of values of query parameters.*

**I would test both solutions (with and without `DATEADD(MINUTE, 0, ...)`) to see if there are any differences in terms of performances.**

Note #1: In order to force an scan SQL2008R2 introduced `FORCESCAN` table hint (SQL2008 comes also with `FORCESEEK` table hint)([references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table)).

Note #2: Basically this function applied on `[Timestamp]` column (`DATEADD(mi,0,[TimeStamp])`)  will have also implications during query compilation / query optimization because no column statistics can be used. Instead because operation is not `=` the predefined selectivity used will be 33% (as far I remember from a video presentation - it's not official / from docs).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that developer made a mistake when write this code.

`DATEADD` can decrease perfomance because indexes will not be used and author did not worry about perfomance
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/608017/dateAdd-inside-where-clause

If filter value can change it's better to write

```
[TimeStamp] < DATEADD(MINUTE, 0, GETDATE())
```

In this case you handle not only cases when you add 0 minutes, but another ones (`DATEADD(MINUTE, 10, GETDATE())` for example)

Comment: Since the question and comments are all speculating that `DATEADD(minute,0,<datetime value>)` are effectively a no-op, *optimizing* its application seems a bit short-sighted.

Comment: Or to put it another way, if it's a no-op, the *best* piece of code to change to is the second code sample included in the OPs question.

Comment: Index (if there is an index on Timestamp column) can be used but not for Seek. Instead, it could be used for Scan. Not always, Seek is better than Scan.

Comment: It seems that author is optimizing it's database and I beleve that index seek on  `TimeStamp` can improve perfomance

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Is it possible that index scan is better than index seek? I never read about it before.

Comment: Create a simple table (ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Col2 VARCHAR(10)). Insert 10 rows having following IDs: 1, 2, ...10 then execute SET STATISTICS IO ON; SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1 WITH(FORCESEEK or FORCESCAN) WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 10) . Look at IO statistics in both cases. Which one (seek or scan) is better ?

Comment: Generally speaking, for DSS/DW/OLAP systems, Scan is better than Seek.

Comment: Or to put it a third way - this answer is only better than the OPs second code sample if `DATEADD(minute,0,<datetime value>)` actually has an effect. If you believe it does have an effect, **that** is what the OP was asking for - so please explain it to them (and the rest of us)

Comment: Bogdan's example is very interesting. However I think it's unlikely developer forced index scan this way and chance of mistake is much more than hidden idea.